# How to format the variable 'money' using AMPscript FormatCurrency?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

```
%%[

var @money=125



set at @USD= /*  Please finish the function */



]%%
```

Comment: You should leverage this doc before asking any question regarding ampscript: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/functions.htm

Comment: This seems very similar to @Diego's question content and style - almost identical. If that is true, I highly recommend not attempting to make multiple accounts to 'spam' questions. It never ends well for anyone.

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask] to understand what is expected of questions on the Stack Exchange platform. If this question and others recently posted, as noted by Gortonington, with an identical format are interview or exam questions, they are not on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [FormatCurrency function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatCurrency.htm).

Give it a try before you ask a question on SFSE.